# How can I change an iteration to be Reactive (Rx)

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive, rx.net

I would like to change the following code to be Observable-based:

```
// 'assets' is a IReadOnly list of StorageFile (approx. 10-20 files)
foreach (var file in assets)
{
    img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));

    img.ImageOpened += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        // Do some work (can contain Task-based code)
    };
}
```

But when I try to change it, I end up with some design problems:

```
assets
    .ToObservable()
    .Select(file =>
    {
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));
        return img.Events().ImageOpened;
    })
    .Switch()
    .Select(event =>
    {
        // Now I'm stuck, I don't have the file...
    })
    .Subscribe(
        _ =>
        {               
        },
        ex => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error on subscribing to ImageOpened"))
    .DisposeWith(_subscriptions);
```

I feel I'm going about this the wrong way...

Comment: Why do you want to change your enumerable to a stream?

Comment: The enumerable itselft doesn't have to be a stream, but I'm trying to change existing code to be more Rx-based.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? What are you try Ing to do?

Comment: What is the type of `img`? It would be helpful to have a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I needed to change my logic due to another limitation with my Image control, but my solution was in the following direction using Zip:

```
Observable
    .Zip(
        assets
            .ToObservable()
            .Do(file => imageControl.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path))),
        imageControl
            .Events()   // Extension class for my events
            .ImageOpened,
        (asset, _) =>
        {
            // Do some work ...
        })
    .Subscribe(
        _ => { },
        ex => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error on subscribing to Zip"));
    .DisposeWith(_subscriptions);
```